# how did the kernel find the right process to send hardware interrupt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

At first, this two things might exist:

1. A system has a table to response hardware interrupt
2. A process has a table to response interrupt send/set by the kernel

If I hit a key on the keyboard, the keyboard will send a interrupt to the CPU/kernel, and the kernel will process this interrupt. But, maybe the current running process is not the foreground one in front of our eyes, it could be a daemon process or something else. So, **how the kernel knows which process should read/response our key stroke?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware interrupts are only handled by the kernel.  The device-specific event is processed and if there is event/data to share with user space then the driver makes that available.  In your example of a keyboard, the device driver services the interrupt, extracting any data and clearing the condition.  The input event representing the data which is pulled from the hardware is then sent to the input subsystem.  A user space process must have the exposed input device handle open and blocked on a read.  The input subsystem within the kernel is managing this.  It's very common to see the same in other drivers: expose a device handle (e.g. /dev/misc/mydevice) which responds to open/close/read/write/ioctl.  When a process performs a "read" and there is no data, the kernel code blocks the calling process causing it to wait until there is data to satisfy the read condition.  I recommend reading up on kernel device drivers.  "Linux Device Drivers" is a great start.

Comment: Thanks for you reply and recommendation. I think it might be the input subsystem's or GUI subsystem's responsibility to choose the right process (and that's quite easy for the GUI subsystem).

Comment: You're now working above what the kernel manages.  From the kernel's perspective, its driver handles the input and provides it to whatever process is waiting on it (if any.)  In the case of a windowing system, like X.org.  X.org is what manages the input and delivers it as GUI specific events to the current foreground process.  At this level it is GUI framework specific as it delivers the event(s) and will not be the same as what hardware and/or the kernel expose.